# CSS List height issue

Tags: html, css

So i'm trying to make a cool navigation but I seem to be stuck with an unusual issue, I cant seem to increase the height of my list items. I want them to be a fixed 45px so when you hover the element it looks good. But its seems that when I do hover the element the list item is only 20px height despite me setting 45px. Any ideas?

Here is my code for the list style

```
.nav li{
height:45px!important;
min-height:45px!important;
display:inline;
list-style: none;
padding-right:40px;
padding-left:40px;
color:#dddddd;
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.60);
margin-left:-4px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/E9Ejd/

Answer (score 2):

First of all your html is a bit strange. Put the anchor inside the list item.

```
<ul><li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li></ul>
```

Then display your  as a block and give it a height.

```
ul li a{display:block; height:45px;}
```

Comment: Indeed, lists (ul/ol) can only have list items as children (or they fail validation as a minimum). List items (li) can, under HTML5, have anything as children (pretty much)

Comment: Just to expand on this a bit, the reason you need to set it to "display:block" is because height is ignored on "display:inline" elements. The height of an inline element can be set with "line-height" rather than "height".

Answer (score 1):

1) reset your list:

```
ul, li {margin:0;padding:0}
```

2) use `display:block` and put all styling (other than `position:` `float:` and `display:`) and put all styling on the `A`-tag, not the `LI`.

3) Never use `!important`.